# Pure JS countdown timer

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I am trying to create a countdown timer, when i click on a button the timer will run according to the value 5, 15, 30 .

I could create a timer but my problem when using the set interval is i can't pass argument to the callback function, when i run the callback function with a preset value it runs fine, but when i am passing an argument it crashes,

```js
var currentTime = new Date();
      function displayCurrentTime() {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        var display = document.getElementById('now');
        display.innerHTML = (hours + '.' + minutes + '.' + seconds);
        return(new Date().getTime());
      }

      setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);

      function endTime(m) {
        var display = document.getElementById('endTime');
        var endingTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
        var hours = endingTime.getHours();
        var minutes = endingTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = endingTime.getSeconds();
        display.innerHTML = (hours + '.' + minutes + '.' + seconds);
        return endingTime.getTime();
      }

      function counter() {
        var display = document.getElementById('counter');
        var countingTime = endTime(1) - displayCurrentTime();
        var days = Math.floor(countingTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((countingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((countingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((countingTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        return (display.innerHTML = (hours + '.' + minutes + '.' + seconds));
              }
```

```html
  <button id="5" onclick="setInterval(counter, 1000)">5</button>
    <button id="15" onclick="setInterval(counter, 1000)">15</button>
    <button id="30" onclick="setInterval(counter, 1000)">30</button>
    <h3>Current Time</h3>
    <p id="now"></p>
    <h3>Your time will end at</h3>
    <p id="endTime"></p>
    <h3>You still have</h3>
    <p id="counter"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any arguments that you want after the delay param in the `setInterval`. Eg. `setInterval(foo, 1000, bar)`. `bar` will be passed as a argument to `foo` every second.

Comment: @Nassif just keep in mind, that you need to remove the old interval, when you set a new one, otherwise you will end up with multiple calls to the same function multiple times in a second if you press the button multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I would simply set the end-time on click and start the counter. So your counter

```js
var endTime = null;
function displayCurrentTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var display = document.getElementById('now');
    display.innerHTML = (hours + '.' + minutes + '.' + seconds);
    //just call counter here if endTime is set. in this case you only need to call updateEndTime on click
    //if(endTime != null) {
    //    counter();
    //}
}
//to avoid 1 second delay on start up
displayCurrentTime()
setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);

function updateEndTime(m) {
    var display = document.getElementById('endTime');
    var currentTime = new Date();
    endTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + (m * 60 * 1000));
    var hours = endTime.getHours();
    var minutes = endTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = endTime.getSeconds();
    display.innerHTML = (hours + '.' + minutes + '.' + seconds);
}

function counter() {
    var display = document.getElementById('counter');
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var countingTime = endTime - currentTime;
    var days = Math.floor(countingTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((countingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((countingTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((countingTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    display.innerHTML = (hours + '.' + minutes + '.' + seconds);
}
```

```html
  <button id="5" onclick="updateEndTime(5);counter();setInterval(counter, 1000)">5</button>
  <button id="15" onclick="updateEndTime(15);counter();setInterval(counter, 1000)">15</button>
  <button id="30" onclick="updateEndTime(30);counter();setInterval(counter, 1000)">30</button>
  <h3>Current Time</h3>
  <p id="now"></p>
  <h3>Your time will end at</h3>
  <p id="endTime"></p>
  <h3>You still have</h3>
  <p id="counter"></p>
```

Btw. you probably should only use 1 `setInterval` and update both counters in 1 call checking if `endTime` is set or not

Comment: you're welcome, like I said, you should only use 1 `setInterval`

Comment: it is a bit not cool to call three functions on click, as you mentioned i should probably use only one setInterval, also it would be way better to summarize all the work in one function and call it up there 
thank you again